# Call a Windows shell command from pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, shell, plpgsql

In **psql** one can **call the windows shell** with '\! [windows shell command]', but I cannot find the equivalent functionality for **pl/pgsql**.

The only possibility is to write and compile a C function that accesses the windows shell.

This only makes sense for a local db installation, for sure; pl/pgsql code is executed on the server not the client, but in this case both run on the same pc.

I need to execute a Python function, but I'd rather not load the postgres python language extension for just this one .py script.

Comment: I'm confused. `PL/pgSQL` is just a language, `psql` is a utility for sending commands written in that language to the database. You could wrap all the PL/pgSQL commands within a python script and just execute that (using the `pg` module, or some other python postgres module).

Comment: Petesh, I am working in PL/pgSQL and could indeed wrap the system calls in a python script, after linking PLPythonu into PL/pgSQL . This is what Pavel Stehule suggests. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Well, no, what I mean is that the `!` syntax is a feature of the `psql` tool. Most tools like this have a bang command to drop to the shell do do stuff at the local command line and drop back to where you were. It has nothing to do with pl/SQL. You've stated that you want the command to run on the client. You've not said where in the pipeline the piece of system-level code is supposed to run (and the statement 'both run on the same pc' seems to imply that you're better off wrapping the pl/SQL invocation in python, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it in plpgsql. This language is "secure" language - that means, so nobody can access any system sources - IO, system functions, ..

When you need to use system sources, then you should to use some "untrusted" language like PLPerlu or PLPythonu. These languages are unsecure - without limited access to system.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plperl.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython.html

Comment: Pavel, this makes a lot of sense.Thank you!